# How do I use a promise.then() when I need the execution of the caller to pause/wait?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm confusing myself with promises.

I have an existing function called `validateCurrentStep` which is fired on click in a multi step form.

Suddenly, there is some AJAX validation that happens on keypress on one of the form elements which means validation may not be complete by the time `validateCurrentStep` is called.

```
validateCurrentStep: ->
    $step = @getCurrentStep()
    if valid()
        return true
    return false
```

I'd like to pull a list of promises and pause this function until the values are returned.

```
validateCurrentStep: ->
    $step = @getCurrentStep()
    $promises = $step.data('promises')

    # how do I delay wait until the `then` is complete?
    $.when($promises).then =>
        if valid()
            return true
        return false
```

Answer (score 1):

[`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) does expect multiple arguments, not an array of promises. In coffeescript, use

```
$.when $promises...
```

which will return another promise for when all of the `promises` have suceeded. You cannot really "pause" the function, but you can make the callbacks to be invoked later.

```
validateCurrentStep: ->
    $step = @getCurrentStep()
    $promises = $step.data('promises')

    # notice the implicit return values in CS
    $.when($promises...).then ->
        valid()

validateCurrentStep().then (isValid) ->
    # do what you need to do
```

Comment: I was really hoping I don't need to change the way this function is called but sounds like that's the only way. Thanks for the heads up on the multiple arguments!